# How to query for rows along with their xml representation?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I need something like

```
select * from tb_listings for xml auto
```

But I need every row to be separate, and not one big xml document.

I have tried something like the following:

```
select id, (select * from tb_listings a where a.id=id for xml auto) as xmldata from tb_listings
```

Expected output is like:

```
id         xmldata 
------------------------------------------------------------
 1         <listing><name>ABC</name><xyz>123</xyz></listing>
```

But it doesn't seem to do what I want and it also takes a very long time to run.

Any ideas would be appreciated. :)

**Edit:** Figured it out:

```
select id, (select top 1 * from tb_listings a where a.id=b.id for xml auto) from tb_listings b
```

Closing.

Comment: queries often speed up if you explicitly specify which columns you want, rather than using *

Comment: @legenden: You should not vote to close your own question in cases like this. Just add your solution as another answer and accept that (you need to wait a while before you can accept your own answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (PK1 int, c1 int, c2 varchar(5), c3 datetime)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (1,2,'abcde','1/1/2009')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (100,200,'zzz','12/31/2009 23:59:59')

--list all columns in xml format
SELECT
    t2.PK1  --optional, can remove this column from the result set and just get the XML
        ,(SELECT
              *
              FROM @YourTable  t1
              WHERE t1.PK1= t2.PK1
              FOR XML PATH('YourTable'), TYPE
         ) as Row
    FROM @YourTable  t2
```

OUTPUT:

```
PK1         Row
----------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           <YourTable><PK1>1</PK1><c1>2</c1><c2>abcde</c2><c3>2009-01-01T00:00:00</c3></YourTable>
100         <YourTable><PK1>100</PK1><c1>200</c1><c2>zzz</c2><c3>2009-12-31T23:59:59</c3></YourTable>

(2 row(s) affected)
```